# Matrix Determinant

Tags: matrix

I have an N by N (N>3) matrix generated from fortran. I would like to find determinant of that matrix using mathematica? I could do this for a 3 by 3 matrix. I can also import the fortran output file to mathematica but how to write down the data in the prescribed format : Det[{{a1, a2, a3}, {a4, a5, a6}, {a7, a8, a9}}] for large N? Writing the data one by one is a tedious job.Kindly help.

fortran output of a 5 by 5 matrix:

```
row1(0.600336   -0.169615    0.054516   -0.003712   -0.038923)
row2(0.637602    0.363638   -0.069266    0.006823    0.035388)
row3(-0.032774    0.876752    0.226435   -0.020353   -0.017496)
row4(-0.024340   -0.144815    0.950590    0.182733   -0.007234)
row5(0.024211    0.030092   -0.161703    0.966905    0.173151)
```

Comment: Please add a sample Fortran output to your question.

Comment: Sir, I have added a fortran output.

Comment: I edited your "fortran output" just a bit further, to make sure it was formatted properly, rather than wrapped.  Are you saying that you have a text file in exactly that form, with possibly more rows for a larger matrix?

Comment: do yuo have the option to fix the fortran. It would be easier if you got rid of the row labels and parenthesis..  You should change your question subject by the way this really has little to do with determinants

Comment: @MarkMcClure if the ForTran "output" is a print file, perhaps your edition isn't correct

Comment: it would actually be a bit of a challenge to coax fortran to generate that output (no lead spaces..)

Comment: @belisarius The OP typed in exactly like that.  All I did was add some leading spaces so that the input would be formatted on the webpage here, as opposed to all run together the way it was. Like everyone, I don't know if that format is correct or not; only the OP can say.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you call your file `out.f`, then a quick way could be:

```
Det[ImportString[StringReplace[Import["out.f", 
     "Text"], "row"~~Shortest[__]~~"("~~
      Shortest[r__]~~")" :> r], "Table"]]
```

gives

```
-0.03777277
```

Answer (score 3):

Am I positive in assuming that the output above is what you have in a text file when switching to Mathematica? Then first read the file line by line. Here *output.txt* is in the directory of Mathematica notebook that you saved.

```
s = Import[NotebookDirectory[] <> "output.txt", "Lines"]
```

This will then take the value parts of strings, split them into elements and convert them to numbers.

```
A = ToExpression[StringSplit /@ (StringTake[#, {6, -2}] & /@ s)]
```

Then calculate `Det[A]`.

Comment: StringTake wouldn't work for row12 for example with two digits. This would work: `StringTrim[#, {"row" ~~ DigitCharacter .. ~~ "(", ")"}] & /@ s`

Answer (score 2):

regexp version..

```
Det@ (First@ImportString[StringReplace[ #, {
    RegularExpression["row\\d*\\(|\\)"] -> ""}] , "Table"] & /@
     Import["badlyformatteddata.txt", "Lines"])
```

->

```
-0.0377728
```

or this which will strip anything before/after the parenthesis.

```
Det@ (First@ImportString[StringReplace[ #, {
       RegularExpression["^.*\\(|\\).*$"] -> ""}] , "Table"] & /@
          Import["badlyformatteddata.txt", "Lines"])
```